# how to reset vscode terminal pane size with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings, vscode-keybinding

##### Question

How can I assign a keybinding to resize the panel to its default height (ie **not min/maximized**)?

##### Background

Often I need to resize the terminal to see more output, while still leaving enough of the editor viewable to compare stuff.

Afterward, I want to have a keybinding that restores the panel to a shorter, less-obtrusive height (eg the default height) without fully minimizing it.

The default keybindings show only the following command related to panel resizing, which is not what I want:

```
// - workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel #
```

##### My environment:

Version: 1.59.0
OS: Linux x64

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not looking for  `"command": "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel"`?

If you first open your terminal to an unobtrusive size you can simply use the keybinding you've chosen to toggle between maximized and your chosen default, and not min/maximized as you say.

So, in `keybindings.json` (Command Palette > "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)"), you can add something like:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+m",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel"
}
```

Comment: hi, yeah I was just looking for a way to 'reset' the un-maximized (but not hidden) size without touching the mouse.  in practice, the easiest solution was to just alter my behavior.  i just avoid dragging the default any higher and forgo the 'big terminal / little editor' view.